# How to communicate between two apps running on devices on the same WiFi network using .NET / Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, network-programming

I have a cross platform app (iOS, Android, Windows Phone and Mac OS) built on Xamarin technology which I would like to enable to talk to other instances on the same WiFi network.
In the best case this would work cross platform, but if communication is possible between devices of the same brand only, it's not a big limitation.

I looked at Bonjour, but obviously that's not cross platform compatible.
What are my options if I want to use pure .NET with as little platform dependency as possible?

Is there a good cross-platform library that can support me?

Comment: Isn't this a simple "how do I use sockets from C#" question?

Comment: @ctacke Kind of. But it requires more: how do I discover the other device? iOS offers Bonjour, but what about the other devices types?

Comment: @LarryOBrien Even if there is something in Apple's OS, it won't help me on Android. That's why I was hoping for something true .NET based which would work x-platform.

Comment: Sorry I missed the xplat nature of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [Salaam](https://salaam.codeplex.com/documentation).

> Salaam is a cross-platform library written in C# and available for
>   Windows versions which could serve .Net Framework 2.0 and upper, Mac
>   OS X, Linux, iOS, Android, Solaris and many other Mono and .Net
>   compatible operating systems and engines including MonoGame, Box2D,
>   XNA and Unity3D and many more.
>
> In a simple word, it is very similar to Apple's Bonjour...